# How to clear the caches in WP / Wordpress or Drupal via url?

Tags: urls

How does one clear the caches in Civicrm via a URL?

Answer (score 6):

I just found this, so thought I'd post it :)

The URL to clear all Civi caches in **Drupal** is **[site-url]/civicrm/clearcache**

The URL to clear all Civi caches in **Wordpress** is: **[site-url]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/job&action=export&id=13&reset=1**

this can be found by going to "**Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs**" and saving the link url of the "**edit > execute now**" link of the **Clean Up Temporary Data and Files** job (via right click?).

One can also execute the scheduled job there....

Comment: this is the link to the page for WP but not the operation itself.

Answer (score 4):

Also at Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and update Paths at this path civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1