# Civicrm upgrade problem - will clearing cache help?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, error, cache

Trying to run upgrade script on wordpress civicrm gives me a new login screen followed by another chance to click the upgrade button follow by another login screen. civicrm 4.6.9 from 4.6.8 wordpress 4.3.1

**How do I flush cache on Wordpress?**

Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /home/mygriefandloss/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Setting.php on line 613

Warning: Illegal string offset 'group_name' in /home/mygriefandloss/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Setting.php on line 516

These errors happen when I just try to access civicrm from menu.

Comment: I don't have Wordpress but I'm assuming CiviCRM's settings are the same. Have you tried Administer --> System Settings --> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths?

Comment: Warning related to 'group_name' can be a cause of mailchimp extension. Do you have that installed? Try disabling mailchimp extension to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here list a few different ways to clear cache: [How to clear the caches in WP / Wordpress or Drupal via url?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/6973/105) including on WordPress.